# Can't integrate Visual Studio 2013 with an add-in

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-addins

I have an add-in that works with Visual Studio 2008, 2010 and 2012. All I have to do is to copy some files to `c:\users\username\documents\Addins` folder, and then check the relevant line in VS Add-in Manager.

I've just installed Visual Studio 2013, and I'm trying to integrate it with that add-in. It does not work. I googled and it says something about changes to add-ins... new VS packages... I lost it.... Just want to make it work with no major changes. Do you know how to?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your .addin file lists support for VS 2013:

> <HostApplication>
>   <Name>Microsoft Visual Studio</Name>
>   <Version>12.0</Version> 
>   </HostApplication>

And the directory to copy files is usually documents\Visual Studio 2013\Addins.

Answer (score 2):

It would be best to convert it to a VSPackage as AddIns are depreciated in VS 2013. As with any other future updates from MS you wouldnt want that to break your addin each time would be the risk.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246938.aspx